# Java Oracle Blob to Blob comparisons failling using PreparedStatement statement

Tags: java, oracle, blob

I try to compare string inside blob saved as byte array to string in SQL query 
from what i understand i need to convert the value to Blob and then compare Blob and Blob 
but im getting error

```
String s = "SELECT * FROM TEST VAL like ?";
Blob blob = conn.createBlob();
blob.setBytes(1, ((String)"yes").getBytes("UTF-8"));
PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement(s);
p.setBlob(1,blob);
p.executeUpdate();
```

but getting exception error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CAST_TO_VARCHAR2'
```

Comment: Well, where is the definition to CAST_TO_VARCHAR2  and the code that calls it?  Also the "Select" query you have is incorrect - missing "FROM"

Comment: Why are you performing this cast: `(String)"yes"`?  It's redundant.

Comment: why from is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The first mistake is that the statement is a SELECT statement :

```
String s = "SELECT * FROM TEST VAL like ?";
```

but you are trying to call `p.executeUpdate();`

According to the documentation of: [PreparedStatement#ecexuteUpdate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate())

> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which
>   must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as
>   INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing,
>   such as a DDL statement.

that is - this method is not intended for execution of `SELECT` statement. Only INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE or an SQL that returns nothins - SELECT returs a resultset.

---

Another mistake is that according to the documentation of [LIKE operator](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52141) their arguments can be only of the following datatypes:

> **char1 LIKE char2 [ ESCAPE asc_chars ]** 
>   All of the character expressions
>   (char1, char2, and esc_char) can be of any of the data types CHAR,
>   VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2. If they differ, then Oracle converts
>   all of them to the data type of char1.

As you see, BLOB datatype are not alloved here as parameter. BLOB datatype was used as a parameter of LIKE operator --> `p.setBlob(1,blob);`, therefore the error was thrown: `ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CAST_TO_VARCHAR2'` because Oracle tried to cast BLOB to VARCHAR2 datatype, but this cast is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks , so if i change the query to VAL =  ? and replace it to executeQuery() is should work ? somwhow ? or there is no way to compare 
Blob to Blob ?